# How to access translated property using knp labs translatable doctrine behaviors

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am using doctrine translatable and i have a entity which have an translatable attribute. This look like this.

```
class Scaleitem
{
    /**
     * Must be defined for translating this entity
     */
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

And i have a file ScaleitemTranslation:

```
class ScaleitemTranslation
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translation;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $text;


    /**
     * Set text
     *
     * @param string $text
     * @return ScaleitemTranslation
     */
    public function setText($text)
    {
        $this->text = $text;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get text
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getText()
    {
        return $this->text;
    }
}
```

I would like to access the text from a controller:

```
$item = $em->getRepository('AppMyBundle:Scaleitem')->find(1);
dump($item->getText());
```

This do not work. Have someone a hint for my issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As showed in the [translatable docs](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#translatable) you can access the translation using:

- `$item->translate('en')->getName();` when you want a specific language
- or adding the `__call` method in the `Scaleitem` entity (not on translated entity):

  ```
  /**
   * @param $method
   * @param $args
   *
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function __call($method, $args)
  {
      if (!method_exists(self::getTranslationEntityClass(), $method)) {
          $method = 'get' . ucfirst($method);
      }

      return $this->proxyCurrentLocaleTranslation($method, $args);
  }
  ```

  to then use `$item->getName();` and always retrieve any "property" in the current locale.