# How to retrieve translation of a "sub entity" using Symfony a2lix knp doctrine behaviors translatable

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, translation, behavior, a2lix-translation

I'm new in symfo but I need to translate content of my site.

I'm using a2lix (last version) and KNP doctrine behaviors (Translatable).

Let's say that I have 2 entities (e.g. Articles and Categories).

As in the doc (https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors) for translations, I'm using 2 classes for Categories (Category and CategoryTranslation).
To retrieve the translations, of my category, I'm using a query with the locale. I get the locale with Request $request ($locale = $request->getLocale();). Here is an example of my controller and the query in my repository.

**Controller**

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $locale = $request->getLocale();

        $entities = $em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Category')->findAllByLocale($locale);

        return $this->render('CTCArtworkBundle:Backend/Artwork:index.html.twig', array(
            'entities' => $entities,
        ));
    }
```

**Repository**
I'm trying to retrieve informations for the locale.

```
public function findAllByLocale($locale){

        return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
                   ->join('a.translations', 'aTrans')
                   ->where('aTrans.locale = :locale')
                   ->setParameter("locale", $locale)
                   ->addSelect('aTrans')
                   ->getQuery()
                   ->getResult()
        ;        
}
```

I don't know if it's a good practice but it works for me. I retrieve fr/en categories in my Twig template like so when I change the url :

```
<tr>
    <th>Category</th>
    <td>{{ category.translations|First.name }}</td>
</tr>
```

**My problem**

For the translation of my article, I do the same. I have 3 properties
- title
- description
- category (I'm using a2lix_translatedEntity (http://a2lix.fr/bundles/translation-form/#bundle-additional))

When I try to render a record of Article, I never retrieve the translation for my category Name but well for title and description.

I also read that (https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#guess-the-current-locale) but I don't really understand. Is that a way to always pass locale ?

What am I doing wrong ?

I'm blocked and don't find any documentation to resolve my problem. Sorry for my english ;-)

Any help would be very appreciate. Many Thanks

Comment: look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232860/how-to-access-translated-property-using-knp-labs-translatable-doctrine-behaviors/29233740#29233740) it might be useful for you.

Comment: @gp_sflover, many thanks, you save my life too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KNP has its own way to guess the current locale, simply by accessing current request scope. The whole "passing locale" thing is useful if you want to pull records for specific locale.

Now, for your category translation. Since you did not include your entities, I will try to show you some examples to access your translations.

In your Category entity, lets say you have a property **name** that would return your category name. Then you can define a simple helper method that would return that name, by current locale:

```
public function getName() {
    if( $name == $this->translate()->getName() ) {
        return $name;
    }

    return '';
}
```

So, what have we done here?

1. **$this->translate()->getName()** - this line looks for your translation entity (in this case that would be CategoryTranslation) and invokes method **getName()** . Then, we either return translated category name, or an empty string if no translation has been added.

And lastly, this is how you can access your category name in your twig template:

Since we defined our helper method, there is no longer any need to access **.translations** in your template. You can simply call:

```
{{ category.name }}
```

Hope you got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

With DoctrineBehaviors v2, you can add this to your Category class:

```
public function __call($name, $arguments)
{
    return $this->proxyCurrentLocaleTranslation($name, $arguments);
}
```

Here's what it does. So, in your Category entity, lets say you have a property **description** that would hold your category description. The code above will generate a corresponding property getter: **getDescription()**. Which ultimately will allow you to use this property in your Twig template:

```
{{ category.description }}
```

Answer (score 0):

And you can also use this

```
{{ category.translate.name }}
```